# User rolls two die and the application tells their luck depending on how quickly they got same numbers on both

Tags: c#, dice

When I run this Application. After I get both the same numbers, I don't get the message "Better luck next time". Can you please tell me what is wrong?

```cs
    using System;
    
    namespace FirstCode
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Random numberGen1 = new Random();
                Random numberGen2 = new Random();
                int roll1 = 5;
                int roll2 = 0;
                int count = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("This is the LUCK indicator \n Press ENTER to roll die and TEST LUCK.");
                
               while (roll1 != roll2)
               {
                   Console.ReadKey();
                   roll1=numberGen1.Next(1,7);
                   roll2=numberGen2.Next(1,7);
                   Console.WriteLine("Roll 1-- " + roll1);
                   Console.WriteLine("Roll 2-- " + roll2);
                   count++;
               }
                
               Console.WriteLine("It took you " + count + " attempts to roll same number on both die.");
               count = 9;
               Convert.ToInt32(count);
               if(count == 1){
                   Console.WriteLine("You are extremely lucky");
               }
               else if (count == 2){
                    Console.WriteLine("You are LUCKY today");
                    }
               else if(count >= 3){
                   if(count <= 5){
                       Console.WriteLine("Your LUCK is average");
                   }
               }
               else {
                   Console.WriteLine("Better LUCK next time");
               }
                
             Console.ReadKey();
            }               
                
                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your last `else` is never reached since `count >= 3` will grab all the rest.

Comment: My bet is : you don't get this message when you do 6 rolls and more. it never goes in the else part of `if(count >= 3){`. Replace `if(count >= 3){ if(count <= 5){ } }` by : `if(count >= 3 && count <= 5) { }`. It's the good time to learn about [Boolean logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

Comment: else if(count >= 3 && count <= 5){
                   Console.WriteLine("Your LUCK is average");
               
           }

Comment: `count = 9;`  Why are you setting it to 9 here? This line, `Convert.ToInt32(count);`, does nothing.  You only need one instance of `Random`, which can be used to roll both dice.

Answer (score 1):

You are messing up the if/else statements. If you want to make it clearer (a bit, at least), maybe you can use a function, that will return the correct message depending on the count :

```
private string GetMessageFromCount(int count)
{
    if (count <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Count cannot be 0 or negative", "count");
    if (count == 1)
        return "You are extremely lucky";
    if (count == 2)
        return "You are LUCKY today";
    if (count <= 5) //we are obviously between 3 and 5 attempts
        return "Your LUCK is average";
    return "Better LUCK next time";
}
```

Then, to signal how lucky people are, just call the method :

```
Console.Writeline(GetMessageFromCount(count));
```